# regex - how to parse with multiple or conditions?

Tags: python, regex

How to parse 3 character alpha with multiple `or` conditions? All text is uppercase [A-Z].

```
+--------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                      string                      |      expected      |
+--------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| ABC DE YHU Q POLGHY11.32 2503.08SA YVR           | ABC, YHU, YVR      |
| ASD AS CCA420.30ASCAT189.72                      | ASD, CCA, CAT      |
| ASD AS CCA420.306DCAT189.72                      | ASD, CCA, CAT      |
| ASD AS CCA420.30D6CAT189.72                      | ASD, CCA, CAT      |
| SEE QA AMS ER STO Q SEESAW14.25M2475.45KL MLS BB | SEE, AMS, STO, MLS |
+--------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Conditions

- 3 alpha in word boundary

OR

- 3 alpha followed by digit
- 3 alpha preceded by exactly 2 alpha-numeric, there can be characters before too
- Don't match if 6 consecutive alpha (e.g. `POLGHY`, `SEESAW`)

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9Pg9G5/3)

Comment: Where in the example do we see a case of "3 alpha preceded by exactly 2 alpha-numeric"? Also, by "alpha", you mean `[A-Za-z]`? Or something broader? (I would expect 'ESA' on the last line, as that's preceded by 'SE' and CAT is not preceded by "2 alpha" on the third line, but still matches?

Comment: Sorry it's the `CAT` ones, only get if preceded by two alpha-numeric but there can be other text before too. Don't know how to explain, I can update conditions

Comment: That means, you also want to get `GHY` from the first string and `SAW` from the last. Right? Why if not?

Comment: If you want 'CAT' from line 3, why don't you want 'SAW' from line 5?

Comment: It's preceded by 2 alpha-numeric, `6D` on third line. I want to exclude ones where it's 6 consecutive alpha like `POLGHY` and `SEESAW`, updated conditions

Comment: While it may be possible, do you really have to do this all in one regexp? Checking for exclusions is easier to do by filtering the results.

Comment: So, why don't you want 'ESA' on line 5? Because it's not followed by a digit? I.e. you want either only the first condition, or all of the other three conditions combined? Shouldn't that still match 'SAW' though? Is 'SAW' excluded because there is an 'S' before 'EE' and "there can be characters before" should exclude [A-Z]?

Comment: @Grismar yes I think that is correct, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A literal interpretation of your conditions would be something like:

```
(\b[A-Z]{3}\b)|([A-Z]{3})\d|[A-Z\d]{2}([A-Z]{3})
```

But from your examples, it appears you're really more after something like:

```
(?:\b|[A-Z\d]{2})([A-Z]{3})(?:\b|\d)
```

But from the conditions and examples as given, it's unclear what your conditions really are.

With added comments, it appears that this is what you're after:

```
(\b[A-Z]{3}\b)|(?:\b|[^A-Z](?:[A-Z\d]{2}))([A-Z]{3})\d
```

But conditions are more like

- either just three capital letters alone, OR
- three capital letters followed by a number, either after a word boundary or when preceded by two alpha-numeric characters, which cannot be preceded by a capital letter

Note that in the result here, you'd be after group 1, not the entire match, which would include the pre- and post-fixes.

Comment: He said "preceded by 2 alphanumeric" so that should be `[A-Z\d]{2}`

Comment: You're right, fixed

Comment: This is not capturing `CCA` for line 2-4

Comment: Noticed and edited - it is now correctly described and matches what you're after. Although I can think of some edge cases you might also not be after, but then you'll have to update the example.

Comment: Thank you! for helping clarify with me and getting better description and answer